# Как сделать запрос с формированием даты mySQL?

Tags: yii2

есть такой запрос

```
SELECT name_film, date( from_unixtime( created_at ) ) created_at
FROM `fl_films`
ORDER BY created_at
```

можно ли его сделать в ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать класс, например:

```
class Films extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'fl_films';
    }
}
```

А потом сформировать запрос к БД, например:

```
$customers = Films::find()
->select(['name_film', 'date(from_unixtime(created_at)) created_at'])
->orderBy('created_at')
->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date(from_unixtime(created_at))
```

к сожалению дает только 2016 правельнее так:

```
Films::find()
->select(['name_film', 'date_format(from_unixtime(created_at),"%d%m%Y") created_at'])
->orderBy('created_at')
->all();
```